# Replace all then lock the replacing words

Tags: vba, ms-word, word-2010

I am trying to replace all and then to lock only replace words, not all.

For example:

Sentence: "I am going to market"
Find: "market" 
Replace: "school"

Then, lock word "school".

```
Dim Datas(500) As String
Dim CariKata As String

Datas(1) = "Shop"
Datas(2) = "Office"

Selection.WholeStory
Selection.Editors.Add wdEditorEveryone
For h = 1 To 2

CariKata = Datas(h)

    For i = 1 To CountWordPhrase(CariKata)
        Selection.find.ClearFormatting
        Selection.find.Replacement.ClearFormatting
        With Selection.find
            .Text = CariKata
            .Replacement.Text = "school"
            .Forward = True
            .Wrap = wdFindContinue
            .Format = False
            .MatchCase = False
            .MatchWholeWord = True
            .MatchWildcards = False
            .MatchSoundsLike = False
            .MatchAllWordForms = False
            .MatchPhrase = True
        End With
        Selection.find.Execute
        Selection.Editors(wdEditorEveryone).Delete

    Next i



ActiveDocument.Protect Password:="123", NoReset:=False, Type:= _
    wdAllowOnlyReading, UseIRM:=False, EnforceStyleLock:=False


Next h

End Sub

Function CountWordPhrase(ByVal KataDicari As String)

Dim Response, ExitResponse
Dim y As Integer


On Error Resume Next



With ActiveDocument.Content.find
    Do While .Execute(FindText:=KataDicari, Forward:=True, Format:=True, _
       MatchWholeWord:=True) = True

       ' Display message in Word's Status Bar.
       StatusBar = "Word is counting the occurrences of the text " & _
       Chr$(34) & x & Chr$(34) & "."

       y = y + 1
    Loop
End With
```

End Function

This script successfully find and lock, but it can't find, replace, and lock.

How to find, replace, and lock?

Comment: Which version of Word?

Answer (score 0):

Protecting small bits of text in Word can be tricky. With 2010 you have two basic options:

1. Use "Read-Only" protection. This lets you lock down the document, specifying certain areas as editable for selected people (or "Everyone"). You'll find the basic functionality in the Developer tab, Restrict Editing button, that displays the task pane. You'd select and mark the entire document as editable, then set the ranges you change as protected.
2. Use content controls, setting the two "Locking" checkboxes. Since I see a line with ContentControls in your code, I'm assuming you're already familiar with them, to a certain extent. The advantage of this approach is that you wouldn't need to be constantly changing the protection level on the document.

In either case, you can no longer use ReplaceAll. You'd need to put the Find in a Loop and after each "hit", do the insertion/protection step, then loop again. There are lots of code examples on the Internet for looping with Find. Search: Word Find Loop

Comment: Based on @Cindy Meister's answer, I can make find and lock function, but I still fail to creat find-replace-and-lock function.

Comment: Can you edit your original question to include the code you now have working? (NOT subsitute - add it at the end.) I suspect it will be a matter of a small change. For example Selection.Text = "replace term"  before you create the content control or ContentControl.Range.Text before you lock the content control.

Comment: It failed. I've played around placing it here and there, but it did not work.

Comment: Try changing the following line like this: Selection.find.Execute Replace:=wdReplaceOne

Comment: Before suggesting, it is better if you try your suggestion with yourself, so you sure it  runs or not.

Comment: I'd love to be able to test, but since you haven't provided exact steps to repro the document you're working in that's not possible. You also don't provide the code that's working up until that point as a starting point for us. The reason the term isn't changing is because your code isn't doing anything to replace the original term. Replace can do that, or you can substitute the term as part of your code - it really should be fairly obvious...